# delete performance in clustered table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My table size details are as follows :

```
  Size : 8.5 TB,  
    total columns : 20 
    Rows : 520,712,026,254
    Cluster by Date_Period(varchar 50) : different values are 'Mar 2019' , 'Apr 2019', 'May 2019' ..... 'Apr 2021' total 25 months of data.
    
    clustering_information 
    total_partition_count : 725451
    total_constant_partition_count : 725440
    average_overlap : 0
    average_depth : 1.0
```

I want to delete 25th month of data and to keep till 24th Month. I am testing delete operation with hardcoded value as of now. The process is monthly.
`delete from table_name where date_period  = 'Mar 2019'` .

But it is taking more then 4 hrs and at last getting timed out.  Why the simple delete is taking time even the field is clustered.  How can i improve it.

Note : I am testing query on Cloned data taken from QA to dev.

Comment: Any chance to get [query profile](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html)?

Comment: The issue is likely that you are using a varchar to cluster your data.  Can you change that field to a date in your table?  If not, perhaps changing the cluster definition to cast it to a date during the clustering, that might be decent, as well.  There are several ways you can test this, but you'd have to create a new version of the table either way (rather than a clone).

Comment: Hi Mike ,  Can' do the same modification in clone itself.. ?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i have cancelled the query after waiting for 2hr ..

Comment: I'll also recommend to file a support ticket with the specifics of this case - they should be able to debug this situation better than us

Comment: Btw, why did you cluster by month and not by day?

Comment: we are getting data as string 'Mar 2021' so clustered on string value only..  have not converted into date or day value... There will be 24 unique values will be there for 2 years data...

Comment: After running into XL the delete is completing in 1 hr now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using a larger warehouse. You might also try disabling the
   cluster key as this might contribute to additional resource consumption and then re-enabling it.
2. Deleting is expensive. Instead of DELETE, try: CREATE
   NEW_TABLE AS (SELECT * FROM CLONED TABLE WHERE DATE_PERIOD <> 'Mar
   2019' ORDER BY DATE_PERIOD) Swap the tables, and maybe add a cluster
   key to the new table. But it's already effectively clustered due the ORDER BY. You will probably want to use at least a LARGE DW for this. Note that the ORDER BY is necessary even though the original table is clustered.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an edge case, and a good opportunity to have support engage with the specifics of your case.

In the meantime I created a 10 billion row clustered table, while trying to reproduce the problem:

```sql
create or replace temp table ten_billionv2
cluster by (m)
as
select to_char(dateadd(minute, seq8(), '1990-01-01'), 'mon yyyy') m, seq8() seq, uniform(1, 10000, random()) value, uniform(1, 10000, random()) value2
from table(generator(rowcount=>100000)) a, table(generator(rowcount=>100000)) b;

select *
from ten_billionv2
limit 10;
```

[image]

This is smaller than the table you describe, but it gives us a good opportunity to see if any of the advice on the other answers and comments apply.

- It took less than 10 minutes to create this table with an L warehouse.
- It's clustered by a string.
- Cloning it was fast.
- Deleting data from it was fast - either from the original or from the clone.

```sql
create temp table ten_billionv2_clone_2
clone ten_billionv2
--2s
;

delete from ten_billionv2_clone_2
where m='Apr 2021'
--18s
;

delete from ten_billionv2
where m='Apr 2021'
--17s
;

delete from ten_billionv2_clone_2
where m='Apr 2190'
--9s
;

delete from ten_billionv2
where m='Dec 11576'
--25s
;

delete from ten_billionv2_clone_2
where m='Dec 11576'
--28s
;
```

[image]

I'll stop my experiments here - but what I would try next is having way more data per month - maybe the time will scale with the number of partitions involved. What I learned so far is that Snowflake is smart about using the clustering algorithm to only scan certain partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making each month a separate table, then union them together in a view.  To drop a month, you just change the view SQL to not include that month.  Another benefit is the data clustering by month will be automatic, and you can use a different column for clustering within each month table if needed.

```
create or replace view ALL_MONTHS as
select * from tbl_March2019
union
select * from tbl_April2019
...
```

Comment: that will be complete change of design , that we can do but in some later phase.